# Build failed with an exception, after flutter upgrade

Tags: dart, flutter

after upgrade my flutter to Channel beta, v0.10.2, when i press F5 to build and run on emulator its error, whats the problem?

```html
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_launch-0.1.2\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutterlaunch\FlutterLaunchPlugin.kt: (33, 42): Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_launch-0.1.2\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutterlaunch\FlutterLaunchPlugin.kt: (34, 44): Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_launch-0.1.2\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutterlaunch\FlutterLaunchPlugin.kt: (50, 40): Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_launch:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

flutter doctor :

```html
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.345], locale en-ID)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.28.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you tried upgrading the related plugin (flutterlaunch)

Comment: yah, already tried update all depedencies, but still not work

Comment: after remove the flutter_launch plugin evrything going normal,
thanks